# How to config eclipse to execute build_native.py?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use cocos2d-x 3.0 beta 2. When I choose run from eclipse, It doesn't execute build_native.py. I have to manually execute it in command line.

How to config eclipse for executing this script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your own custom external tool to execute external scripts or commands and add them to your project configuration. Check http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click on your project.
2. Select Properties
3. Select C/C++ Build Path
4. Under Build Command, write the following command:
   python ${ProjDirPath}/build_native.py

Following is a screenshot of this process.[image]

I hope it helps.